# ElementUi: Individual components have same size as full bundle?

Tags: webpack, vuejs2, webpack-2, laravel-mix, element-ui

I want to use some handpicked components from [ElementUi](https://element.eleme.cn/#/en-US/component/installation) instead of the full bundle.

I am using [laravel-mix](https://laravel-mix.com/) to compile and minify my bundles.

It seems that it does not matter if I only register 2 components or the complete bundle in my `App.vue`, because

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import { Button, Select } from 'element-ui';
import 'element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/index.css';

Vue.use(Button)
Vue.use(Select)

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

and

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import ElementUI from 'element-ui';
import 'element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/index.css';

Vue.use(ElementUI);

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

both end up to be compiled into `app.js` of size `687kb`. Why is that?

This is my `webpack.mix.js` configuration:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.webpackConfig({
   externals: {
    vue: 'Vue'
  }
});

mix.options({
  extractVueStyles: 'public/css/components.css',
  purifyCss: true,
});

mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
```

If I try the same with Buefy as explained [here](https://buefy.org/documentation/start) then the bundle size has a big difference, table + input is only `50kb` while the full bundle is `222kb`.